# Image in TSpeedbutton with TImageList

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, timagelist

I tried to create a toolbar, using a `TToolbar` with `TActionList`, `TSpeedbutton` and `TImageList`.
I used square images with 32px, but when I chose the image, by ImageIndex, in the TSpeedButton, the image size is less than 32px, I think is 16px.

How I can set the size of image in `TSpeedButtons` using a `TImageList` ?

Here's a MVCE:

```
unit Unit50;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls,
  System.ImageList, FMX.ImgList;

type
  TForm50 = class(TForm)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    Action1: TAction;
  end;

var
  Form50: TForm50;

implementation
{$R *.fmx}
end.
```

DFM:

```
object Form50: TForm50
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form50'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton
    Action = Action1
    Enabled = True
    Images = ImageList1
    ImageIndex = 0
    Position.X = 360.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 120.000000000000000000
    Visible = True
  end
  object ActionList1: TActionList
    Images = ImageList1
    Left = 272
    Top = 128
    object Action1: TAction
      Text = 'Action1'
      ImageIndex = 0
    end
  end
  object ImageList1: TImageList
    Source = <
      item
        MultiResBitmap.Height = 32
        MultiResBitmap.Width = 32
        MultiResBitmap = <
          item
            Width = 32
            Height = 32
            PNG = {
              89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200000020000000200806000000737A7A
              F4000000017352474200AECE1CE90000000467414D410000B18F0BFC61050000
              06BA4944415458477557596C9455143EB374BA4C2804A3159382096A30A96C2F
              2A2F4AE20216431482C4170DFAA028C4E89B31C6109F545CA26C01890F2A9620
              098B0F22124A69A1C1C428469BB085049C0A48D7994EDB593CDF59EEFC7F837F
              339D7FEEBDFF3DDFF9CE77CEB97FE2CA378BAB55E2BF2A512241F25DA910A592
              C4034493A52ABE28994CF047E779B9AC9D2C5769D7F976BE4FF038AFB30DB044
              EEB114E3F8E3E771EF17C66037897F6280FF55781E4B5229FDC6FA344FA4526A
              BCCCC0E40210FE4AF3380CB931999BF25B8C8A6370D20CD83D9E4BBAE75894E0
              79007140E2291B0323B68F823420B29F6F6CDE06E486D5D971EF8524018A7D2B
              944CB1456CAAE8953AFC84B7C6A284A30600546B489CE228B5B207E88A007086
              923C5EB1303873B59555D0AC71C29ABAB4FE86193168C8EB987601C8F157C615
              88DFE37978864D24F6A68B2453897137ECA005405236512DF8A7CCB4006D097B
              C9AC4D6A488D2D7C9900ED1B7BC198D2A7209D6030E0ACD90D34A0D37810CF00
              219C73BF403F8C80017C4A8897DCEB9828191B9B7600BAC222A9B2B7025CD880
              C031A6427456C4AE5AADA1C46086E95FB3B920E2736FB1198C624E7C93E45570
              7E497C814F3DD14DE198A47052C00651DA4318250E2B0BCD4465941527AAB4EC
              FD3C7D78603CE432C232595603D08890674CBB67AC6AD95A412850A7DDF51274
              00A7C01EE25C3251696A11BDBDBA413C38F25B899ED894A75F2F954594D8FF5C
              AE4CBB8E4ED0A6BD455AFAC8A3D4DADA2A71179583B6C825069C7603564B4966
              0795D04228E9081A3D46301CC9506AAA27CA17DD6DB5D279F26430972FE46960
              6080068786686870908686876890BF47F3792A954A343939190327E1FA7BCF62
              682344520C0A08A237BF2AD2EF97CBB5399DB4F8EA77679702F0104469F62205
              56525C5E0FFF7098CE5FBC104088B8255E715C328042F40EC26057AD62D664E7
              AA9EFAB8A79B945AA6B73056A04F3FFF2C188FD60E919E140F134B85E9C00288
              724636682C96295A136A690B23FFE7F9814307E9CBDDBB05A388CFEA0558B666
              A4135E07D07C000280DEDD53540D7813F17B77D91A8F0BCFABA0FF2E97CB74F1
              D245316471D27A10E8E42C7091597443410103A7CF79FC3548F5F5AC422BBD1E
              366CB666F52A71E28FB367E944676728B7994C861A1B1B83A88DE4B806A4ED7B
              DDB0AE071497AE71DD56C951DB036D74A2BB9B9E7EF619FAE9E763F4DCDAB5C6
              8CE6716BEB6C6A5FBE8CDED8B881162E5A14440926963CB42456C7BD0678414A
              4A7B8DE69AE1EBFAB3148C6CD9B65D46B1E1F0F030BDBE61636852185BF7F24B
              54E05483B7D3A74F8F35A87BE6CE5556456D35B9FB3941B3C018D09AADB5E0DF
              116D4E80FFD8D2A534323222A9D4DCDC4CAB990995034797016C58BF9EF61F38
              48F3E6DD4FAFBDFA4AA87E5231EBEA42F90588D8E105B67356073C3010202ADE
              CEA3E3B4B75B0B47D0899500370EE4C78E770AB0A959E06BC6C7C769FBCE1D01
              44D0AF791E63C0BB21E61EBC371D1A8EB9EBFA939FD332699A5697A2FCE8A8EF
              1958094678C3FEFEFE1AB808039EF6A201F401EDFF9CCFA934F14189E6CFE183
              A11F36A6C8178CB464EB69CBE36DB4EEC517625530CA04F4D1D37B4AEB0CDF97
              4BE5D85A8CA7DE5A35EB3D3FF3C97981F334C58743003BFBCF6D74D7ECFB68FE
              8285D4BE6205F5F6F6DAD92C41378B9394E1CEF4C1D7DF4B08A20DA6A3E33BBA
              71FD0695B8F69FF9E50CA5D369AD357620116DA1DCA3805DFD76B117364ACE5C
              40C9DB1F0ED463D3FDA74B214DB66EF9A276A6E33D9E5CFE14AD5CB9925AEE6C
              A1868646CA66B33470F3267574748872FEEAEBA3B14221D668DA162E88852A71
              850188E318CECCA4C4B4B994CACEA26ADD0C3E7767E9F240135D1D6EE08DC608
              82FA78F34754E10AD7CCE9562C16A5CB79F73CCE8D09F3F9D1BCA4EBB5EBD728
              5D97A64CA69E9AB24D54DFD04077B4B48430480343378CAA285449D4079BD877
              6A82761C990819014FF39CF7B876ECDC25F0E7CCB99B9A9A9A044C2E97A38E7D
              7B63E28C2B957F59951300AAB1689FB73381864AB488BAF0FC27DCD7FD986673
              5D3D3D616F183F84967BE1BC8C79B593F33FE26DCF84DE80357E20D107D42032
              421B94F5211EF4F780B1F12A6DFB7182BAFB4A3454A8D2112ECDB9FE1C759FEA
              11E1F951F056EE7BA8C4555E180B81786A20F445454138288CF8BB81AFC5B2AD
              7DED919E1DD9D8533882445F03E3A70F2944A87E8101B9D1371FDF23743E43EE
              C77399C7A326163F5B4C2DB78EC15F48A3EC688B304F81C3CFFFFAB2022C7EF0
              B06CB4A2847383DCDABB55388A2B79B7BCF438E21D4617C979C03D758AB10174
              A097BEAAF94718B30C1100B66CEAFBA10B2D81B72473242A3E7FEE3F2E62C156
              E3396C9D0000000049454E44AE426082}
            FileName = 'C:\Users\Johan\Pictures\avatar.png'
          end>
        Name = 'avatar'
      end>
    Destination = <
      item
        Layers = <
          item
            Name = 'avatar'
            SourceRect.Right = 64.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 64.000000000000000000
          end>
      end
      item
        Layers = <
          item
            Name = 'avatar'
          end>
      end>
    Left = 272
    Top = 256
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the image list itself set to 32x32? By default it's 16x16 unless you change it, and assigning any larger size image automatically resizes them to fit the given size.

Comment: 16x16 is the size of the image inside the style - yes it is a fixed size. Simply customize ths style

Comment: Right click on the control, edit style, find the imagecontrol, resize it, save - thats it

Comment: Imagelist was added to FMX in XE8 IIRC, so I've retagged your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glyphsize of a TSpeedButton is defined in the stylesheet.
Only there can you change it.

Here's what to do:

First right click the button and choose: edit style (either default or custom).

[image]

Choose the glyph in the structure window and change its size to 32x32.

[image]

Click <kbd>Apply and close</kbd>

You may need to resize the SpeedButton so that it has enough space to display the glyph.
*(Ideally you'd do the resize of the speedbutton in the (default) style, but I've taken a shortcut here).* 
It will now display in 32x32.  [image]

On a different device you may want to use a different style sheet.
Esp. on some of those ultra high resolution phones.
If so make sure you have have multiple resolution images in your imagelist. If you don't FMX will rescale your image which will not look optimal.